# SQL rent due at different frequencies

Tags: sql

I have a FirstRentPaymentDate date field and a RentFrequency field with four possible values (Week,Fortnight,Month,Year).

Time on the date field is irrelevant but are all set to 12:00:00.

How could I work out if FirstRentPaymentDate for a frequency equals today using a SQL query?

Comment: Figure it out the calculation for each possible frequency, and then use the `case` statement

Comment: well, I would store "lastPaid" date as well. Then run your query ( stored procedure ), calculate days between today and last paid ( `...WHERE now/sysdate > firstrentpaymentdate` enables check if he has to pay yet) divided through your frequency ( best stored as a integer value - eg. days ) multiplied with rent value => payment value. And dont forget to update lastPaid afterwards.

Comment: @Jamie what database you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this that doesn't require a lastpaid date:

```
select 
firstdate
,frequency
from sampledata
WHERE
CASE   WHEN frequency = 'week' THEN DATEDIFF(DD,firstdate,getdate()) % 7
        WHEN frequency = 'fortnight' THEN DATEDIFF(DD,firstdate,getdate()) % 14
        WHEN frequency = 'month' AND Day(firstdate) = Day(getdate()) THEN 0
        WHEN frequency = 'year' AND Day(firstdate) = Day(getdate())
                                AND Month(firstdate) = Month(getdate()) THEN 0
END = 0
```